# Swift closure capture array by reference

Tags: swift, closures, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, inout

In Swift Collections are pass by value by default and we can user `inout` to make it pass by reference in function arguments but how can we do it in closure capture variables?

```
var list = [1, 2, 3]
func edit(inout list: [Int]) {
    list.append(4)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        list.append(5)
    }
}
edit(&list)
...// after dispatch_async was executed 
NSLog("\(list)")
```

Result will be [1, 2, 3, 4]

How can I modify the original variable () inside closure?

**UPDATE:**

Actually I have a workaround to handle this case by putting the array into an object so I can pass this object to the function by reference and we can modify the same array instance inside the function. but I want see any clever way to archive that

Answer (score 2):

For getting a variable escape from a closure you need `@escaping`, check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) out. A workaround is to put a completion function as an argument rather than an `inout` variable.

```
class MyClass {
    static func edit(_ list: [Int], _ completion: @escaping ([Int]) -> ()) {
        var list = list
        list.append(4)
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            list.append(5)
            completion(list)
        }
    }
}

var myList = [1, 2, 3]
MyClass.edit(myList) { (list) in
    myList = list
    print("My list after editing: \(myList)")
}
print("My list without editing: \(myList)")
```

**Note**: The above example is for Swift 3 where `inout` parameters are not allowed to be captured in closures. Based on your post, you may be using a lower version of Swift where you might be able to use `inout` rather than setting a mutable copy of the *list*: `var list = list`. However, the logic is very similar.

For more information, check the **[Limiting inout capture to @noescape contexts](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0035-limit-inout-capture.md)** in Swift evolution:

> Swift's behavior when closures capture `inout` parameters and escape
>   their enclosing context is a common source of confusion. We should
>   disallow implicit capture of `inout` parameters except in `@noescape`
>   closures.

Comment: Thanks for your response but any chance that to implement it without access any instance variables inside the function? you can treat it like a static function

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is a way to get back the new copy of array and we can update the instance array variable in the completion closure. but I want  to know any chance that "directly" modify the original array after passing into a function . sorry for my bad explanation in the question. I have tried your code and the result for the global `list` variable is still [1, 2, 3]

Comment: I updated my answer again to use `myList` rather than `list` to make it less confusing. To get the edited `myList` you need to wait until the edit gets completed. If you want to edit the `myList` directly, just make it as a class-level variable in your class and use something like `self.myList` in the closure. As you don't want to go for that approach at the first place, you cannot modify the `myList` directly. For the reason, check out the link I provided in my answer.